# SDF Metadata Import fails when structure information is missing

Tags: bugs, import, chemistry

*UPDATE 04 Sept 2020*:  This behavior been fixed in Mathematica 12.1.

---

*Background Information:* In Mathematica 12.0, [SDF Import](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/SDF.html) automatically triggers the generation of [Molecule[]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Molecule.html) representations.  SDF files contain both structural information as well as metadata, and a valid SDF need not contain the structural information.

*Problem:* Mathematica fails to import valid Metadata, if structure information is missing.  This is out of spec for the SDF format.

*Demonstration:* First, retrieve an SDF file containing two substance records from PubChem

```
retrieveSDF[sids_List] := With[
  {url = URLBuild[
     {"https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/substance/sid/",
      StringRiffle[sids, ","], (*comma-separated SIDs*)
      "/record/sdf"}]},
  URLExecute[url, {}, "Text"]]

ImportString[retrieveSDF[{50608295, 3272}], "SDF"]
```

[image: output from ImportString]
This is totally understandable---substance 50608295 doesn't contain any structure information, so it is asking too much to generate a Molecule[].

But it's record *does* contain valid Metadata.  Writing the SDF to disk and Import[]-ing only the "Metadata" data elements returns a failure.

```
Export["example.sdf", retrieveSDF[{50608295, 3272}], "Text"]
Import["example.sdf", {"Metadata"}]
```

[image: output from Import of Metadata only]

(despite the fact that valid Metadata *is* in fact available in the `example.sdf` file---seen by `Import["example.sdf", "Text"]` or just opening)

*Audience participation question:* Can anyone try this on Mathematica <12 ? SDF handling has been around since version 7, but I suspect that the use of the new Molecule[] functionality in version 12 has broken this.

*Update:* @BobTheChemist reports that it behaves properly (returns Metadata) in Mathematica 11.3, so I've upgraded the question to the "bug" tag)

Comment: V11.3 yields Metadata for the record.  It reports `None` instead of `$Failed` for the `ImportString` command.

Comment: I can fix this for 12.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the support functions called by `Import` is checking if the molecule has no atoms, and if so then it returns `$Failed`.  This is just because the developer was short-sighted and didn't see a use for a molecule-less SDF file.

This is fixed in the current sources for the next release.  For version 12.0 we can do a "surgical strike" on the existing code to fix the issue.

```
Molecule;(*this symbol will autoload the package*)
DownValues[Chemistry`Private`MoleculeFileParseDump`getMoleculeFromSDF] = ReplaceAll[
    DownValues @ Chemistry`Private`MoleculeFileParseDump`getMoleculeFromSDF,
    HoldPattern[If[Less[_["atomCount", _], 1], ___]] :> Null
]
```

Evaluating the above should fix the problem.

Comment: Confirming that this fixes the issue in version 12.0: generic Import[] returns Molecule[]s with zero atoms having the correct MetaInformation; Import[] of Metadata only correctly returns an Association.